# Hide Includes Directory From Users For Jetty Web App

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am creating a project using Jetty 9 (and Maven), and have the following directory structure:

```
src/
    main/
        java/
            ...
    resources/
    webapp/
        includes/
            footer.jsp
            header.jsp
        static/
            style.css
        index.jsp
```

I am embedding Jetty in my jar, and am using a `WebAppContext` with a context path of `/` and a resource base of `src/main/webapp`. This works, however, users can visit `/includes/footer.jsp` etc. in their browser, which is not ideal (especially since they rely on parameters which will be set by the including scripts). Is there a way to fix this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JSPs that you don't want directly accessible by a browser, put them under the `WEB-INF` directory.

Such as this:

```
src/
    main/
        java/
            ...
    resources/     
    webapp/
        WEB-INF/
            includes/
                footer.jsp
                header.jsp
        static/
            style.css
        index.jsp
```

That way other JSPs, like `index.jsp` can reference the footer and header, but browsers cannot.